# How can I change the height of the BottomPopUp in RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, popup, rx-swift

I use RxSwift in my project
After I called an API in Viewmodel and transferred to ViewController, I took the number of data. Then I want to change the Popup height with the number of data. How can I do it?

I try to use a variable to handle it. But it doesn't work

I init a variable to hold the height of the Popup
[image]

Then I set the height for the Popup

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you have not provided enough code to answer the question, but generally I sure what is happening here is that your code is trying to read the value of `heightOfVC` before the value has been set by the `do(onNext:)` statement.

The best solution would likely be to make `heightOfVC` (and `popupHeight`) conform to the Observable contract. Ideally, you would do this by making them `Observable<CGFloat>` but you could also use `BehaviorSubject<CGFloat>` or any of the other types that follow the contract (implement the `ObservableConvertibleType` protocol.)

Comment: I try to use a subject to control it.  But before my API was called, "popupHeight" was implement, so the height of the popup can not change. Do you understand?

Comment: Then the implementation must be changed so that when the data comes in, you can change the popup hight.